# How to connect mac to hadoop/hdfs cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I have CDH for running in a cluster and I have ssh access to the machine. I need to connect my Mac to Cluster, so if I do hadoop fs -ls , it should show me the content of the cluster. 
I have configured HADOOP_CONF to point to the configuration of the cluster. I am running CDH4 in my cluster. Am I missing something here , Is it possible to connect ?

Is there some ssh key setup that I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of things you will need to ensure to do this:

1. You need to set your `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable to point to a directory that carries config XMLs that point to your cluster.
2. Your Mac should be able to directly access the hosts that form your cluster (all of them). This can be done via VPN, for example - if the cluster is secured from external networks.
3. Your Mac should carry the same version of Hadoop that the cluster runs.